# Where can I ask a question about lighting?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

Where in the SE network can I ask a question about lighting in the context of special effects? Specifically, how to reflect/scatter light upwards?

I was thinking the physics site. Would this be correct? Is there another site that would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps your question may on-topic for **[Audio-Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/)**, a 'Q&A for engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts spanning the fields of audio, video, and media creation'. They already have a few question on [lighting](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lighting).

DIY questions can be asked on **[Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lighting?sort=votes&pagesize=15)**, although the sites based more so on traditional practical lighting as apposed to lighting for entertainment.

You can also propose a new site on **[Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)** (if you have the determination to do so). Making a new site is a fairly time consuming process which involves gathering plenty of like-minded individuals to commit.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quwaVmp5Gk0&t=3m26s) with a real box. Audio & Video still the best place?

Comment: Physics may be an appropriate place to ask if such an effect is even possible in the real world.

Comment: So should I start out at Physics asking if this is possible in the real world, and then if so post a question in the Audio & Video section?

Answer (score 3):

Unless it's a question about the physical process by which light is reflected from surfaces, Physics is unlikely to be appropriate. If you're asking about this in relation to camera use, try the [Photography](http://photo.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Or maybe Game Development if it's for a game engine?

Comment: Ah, yes, true. Lighting for a computer rendering of a scene would be off topic on Physics, but might go to Game Dev.

Comment: The Photography site would likely also cover any lighting to do with Theater or other large-scale (or small scale) productions.

Comment: It's not game dev, it's real world. It's not camera related either. Might sound crazy, but I want to achieve something like this (or close enough): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quwaVmp5Gk0&t=3m26s in a real box. Question involved light, mirrors/reflection, and light diffusion.